# Implicit and Explicit Casting between Classes and Subclasses

Tags: java

Given the question below, I am struggling to understand implicit and explicit casting, why does the variable 'a' below require explicit casting while variable 'b' does not?

Consider the following classes:

```
class A implements Runnable{ ...}

class B extends A implements Observer { ...}
```

(Assume that Observer has no relation to Runnable.)

and the declarations :

```
  A a = new A() ;

  B b = new B();
```

Which of the following Java code fragments will compile and execute without throwing exceptions? The answer is:

```
Object o = a; Runnable r = (Runnable) o;
Object o = b; Runnable r = (Runnable) b;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `o`. Because `o` is an `Object`. While `b` is an instance of `B`. Basically, your second example is **not** `Object o = b; Runnable r = (Runnable) o;` which also requires a cast.

It is true that `Observer` has no relation to `Runnable`, but class `A` **does**. And class `B extends A` (in addition to implementing `Observer`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Elliot. But I don't understand how runnable and object are related? All I can think of is that object is a superclass of runnable so explicit cast is mandatory while case 2 of b is not so no need.

Comment: All `Runnable`(s) are also `Object`(s). Not all `Object`(s) are `Runnable`(s). But all `B`(s) are `Runnable`(s) and `Observer`(s) and `A`(s) and `Object`(s). `class A implements Runnable` is implicitly `class A extends Object implements Runnable`

Comment: Wonderful thank you so much for the explanation since Object is not always a Runnable when need to do an explicit cast to tell the compiler that it will be. While b is a runnable so is definitely a runnable and no need of explicit cast. Thank you soo much :) I really appreciate your help.